# mktime() overwrite time_t in C

Tags: c, mktime

I have a problem with `mktime` in c:

```
time_t t_fim;
time(&t_fim);

struct tm* p_fim;
struct tm* c_fim;
p_fim = localtime(&t_fim);
c_fim = localtime(&t_fim);

......

p_fim->tm_year = ano-1900;
p_fim->tm_mon = mes-1;
p_fim->tm_mday = dia;
//here the p_fim date is good

c_fim->tm_mday -=47;
mktime(c_fim);

printf("Pascoa %d %d %d\n", p_fim->tm_mday, p_fim->tm_mon + 1, p_fim->tm_year + 1900);
printf("Carnaval %d %d %d\n", c_fim->tm_mday, c_fim->tm_mon+1, c_fim->tm_year + 1900);

//here the c_fim is good with -47 days but the `p_fim` is now equal with `c_fim`
```

The `mktime` is changing the value of `p_fim`, how to solve that?

Comment: Where do you think your `p_fim` and `c_fim` variables point to? In the code you've shown, they are *never* initialized or otherwise set to point to valid memory.

Comment: I edited the code now

Comment: Well, you should read this documentation for [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/), especially the part that says: *"The returned value points to an internal object whose validity or value may be altered by any subsequent call to gmtime or localtime."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the pointers

```
struct tm p_fim;
struct tm c_fim;
p_fim = *localtime(&t_fim);
c_fim = *localtime(&t_fim);
```

Or, if you're on a POSIX system, try [`localtime_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) instead